# regex multiple parentheses

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

```
$str = "<p>(a)(3) asdf (10) asdf</p>";
```

Trying to pull the second set of parentheses using php preg_match_all

Very big doc I'm parsing, so currently have this:

```
preg_match_all("=(?:<p[^>]*>|<p[^>]*>Note|<i>|</i>)\((.*)\)=siU", $str, $matches);
```

Pulling things like this fine:

```
<p>(a)
<p>Note(a)
<i>(a)
</i>(a)
```

All returning (a)

I'd like to also search for any time I see this: `<p>(a)(3)`

So I need the second paren and its value returned like (3)

And I do not want any other paren + value like the (a) or the (10)

Comment: You can use the curly-braces button above the code window in order to format parts of your question as code.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
preg_match_all("=(?:<p[^>]*>(:?Note)?|</?i>)\((.*)\)(?:\((.*)\))?=siU", $str, $matches);
```

Comment: That would only give you (a) need to get (3) the second set of parentheses

Comment: Well, but I added another () after for that... The only potential problem I see is that it would also get <p>note(a)(3) - I don't know if that's a problem or not though.

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for this:

```
$string = "<p>(a)(3)
<p>Note(ddd)ssssss(a)(3)
<i>dkdkdjkdjkdjkjdkjdk(3)
<i>abc(a)(9)
</i>(a)(3)";


preg_match_all('%<.*?>([\w]+)?(\(.*?\))?(\(3\))%i', $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
echo   $result[3][$i]."<br>" ;
}
```

echo's :

```
(3)
(3)
(3)
(3)
```

if you need to match the whole line you may use:

```
preg_match_all('/(<.*?>([\w]+)?(\(.*?\))?(\(3\)))/i', $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i++) {
echo   $result[1][$i]."<br>" ; 
}
```

echo's:

```
<p>(a)(3)
<p>Note(ddd)ssssss(a)(3)
<i>dkdkdjkdjkdjkjdkjdk(3)
</i>(a)(3)
```